# Racket two lists lambda

Tags: list, racket

I tried to do my first steps with "lambda" in Dr Racket. (Advanced language)

Everything was fine until I tried out the following piece of code:

```
(map (lambda (list1 list2)
     [map list (foldr + 0 (map * list1 list2 ) ) ]    )
   (list 1 2 3 4 5)
   (list 6 7 8 9 10) 
)
```

I tried to adapt my code according to the Racket dokumentation as good as possible.
But I just don't get what's wrong here.
http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._racket/private/map..rkt)._map))

It should output a single list consisting of the droduct of the 2 input list elements with the same index.
Console output says:

```
map: 2nd argument must be a list, given 1
```

whereas 1 is always the first element of list1

Subconsciousness says I just messed with ( ) anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the arguments to the `lambda` mean in a `map`. The arguments to the `lambda` are not the lists, they are elements of the lists.

In a normal one-argument map it's not:

```
(map (lambda (list1)
       ....)
     (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

But actually:

```
(map (lambda (elem1)  ; elem1 is an element of the list
       ....)
     (list 1 2 3 4 5))
```

It's the same with two-argument map. The arguments to the lambda are *elements* of their respective lists:

```
(map (lambda (elem1 elem2)  ; elem1 is an element of the first list, elem2 is an element of the second list
       ....)
     (list 1 2 3 4 5)
     (list 6 7 8 9 10))
```

In your example, the two lists are `[Listof Number]`, so the arguments to the `lambda` are `Number`.

```
(map (lambda (elem1 elem2) ; elem1 : Number, elem2 : Number
       ; here you have two numbers, so you can multiply them,
       ; but `map`-ing over the numbers doesn't make sense
       (* elem1 elem2))
     (list 1 2 3 4 5)   ; [Listof Number]
     (list 6 7 8 9 10)) ; [Listof Number]
```

Comment: Ok, I got that. Is there any way to get a list inside of a lambda or do i need to define a function for that purpose?

Comment: @Aki If you don't need the `map` there is no need for the outer `lambda`. You ca just use the lists in place or you can make a procedure that tales two lists and pass it with the `list` expressions in your code to get what you want.